# convert parent-child array into ul li

Tags: php, pdo

I get username (child) and referral (parent) records from database and put them into arrays by code below :

```
$sql = "SELECT username, referral FROM acc_status";
        $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array());
        $data = array();
        while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $data[] = $row;
        }


        $map = array(); 
        foreach ($data as $node) {
            // init parent
            if (!array_key_exists($node['referral'], $map)) {
                $map[$node['referral']] = array();
            }

            // add to parent
            $map[$node['referral']][$node['username']] = & $map[$node['username']];
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($map["123"]); //get parents and child of username "123" only.
        echo '</pre>';
```

And here is the output :
[image]

Now I want to covert the array into ul and li list, below is the code :

```
       function printTree($tree) {
            if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) {
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach($tree as $node) {
                    echo '<li>'.$node['referral'];//error here
                    printTree($node['username']);//error here
                    echo '</li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        }
        printTree($map["123"]);
```

I am getting 2 errors :

1) **Notice: Undefined index: referral**

2) **Notice: Undefined index: username**

How to fix the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be brief here, put simply the name of your referral and username is actually your index. So for `$node['username']` it would be qqq I do not have my computer with me to show the working code however that's what it will be.